# Forcing distinct breaks (months) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get this plot that consists of multiple colored lines, one representing each year, to display only the months along the X axis. Once I use `format()` as a value for X in `aes`, I can only use `scale_x_discrete`. From there, I can't figure out how to get only the months to be displayed, and to be displayed only once.

The plotting is correct, but the breaks and labels are incorrect. Most importantly, the breaks. Because the days of the year generally do not overlap, I'm getting way too many break values as well. You can see the two commented out lines next to each other, where I was trying to solve the issue.

All I really want is the X axis to form breaks at, and be labeled by the months.

Data set: [Retail_Gas_Prices.csv](http://share.kevin-funk.com/Retail_Gas_Prices.csv)

```
require(ggplot2)  # ggplot
require(reshape)  # melt
require(scales)   # date_format

# monthtext <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
gp <- read.csv("Retail_Gas_Prices.csv")
gp$Month <- substr(gp$Date, 1, 2)
gp$Year <- substr(gp$Date, 7, 10)
gp$Date <- as.Date(substr(gp$Date, 1, 10), "%m/%d/%Y")

coord_radar <- function(...) {
  structure(coord_polar(...), class = c("radar", "polar", "coord"))
}

gas_ra_plot <- ggplot(gp, aes(x=format(Date, '%m:%w:%d'), y=Weekly.US, group=Year, color=Year)) +
  geom_line()+
#   coord_polar()+
  labs(title = "Gas Prices by Month")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.0, 0.0))+
#   scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1,12,1), expand = c(0.0, 0.0))+
#   scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(min(gp$Date),max(gp$Date), length(gp$Date)/12), expand = c(0.0, 0.0))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.0))+
  ylab("Cost in Dollars") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+

  theme(strip.background = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(
    colour = "#dddddd"))


print(gas_ra_plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gp <- read.csv('http://share.kevin-funk.com/Retail_Gas_Prices.csv')

require(ggplot2) 
require(scales)

#parse the datetimes
gp$Date <- strptime(as.character(gp$Date),"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p %z",tz="GMT")

#create year variable
gp$Year <- format(gp$Date,"%Y")

#create dates with the same year (2013)
gp$Date1 <- as.Date(format(gp$Date,"%m-%d"),"%m-%d")

#might be better to make this 2012 due to Feb-29
gp$Date1 <- as.Date(paste0("2012-",format(gp$Date,"%m-%d")),"%Y-%m-%d")


gas_ra_plot <- ggplot(gp, aes(x=Date1, y=Weekly.US, group=Year, color=Year)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%d"))

print(gas_ra_plot)
```

Comment: Seriously...what would I do without you guys! (probably not graduate on time).

Comment: Also, could you possibly explain what is going on with the 3rd and 5th line of code? When I run this, and look at the data frame, there's something kind of odd. The Date column only has 9 values, while Date1, Year, and everything else has all 980 columns filled.

Comment: I guess you mean rows. The data.frame consists of 981 rows and I cannot reproduce, what you describe. It might be related to your locale. You should read `?strptime`.

Comment: This is what my data looks like now: ...and the Date1 column seems to have added the current year, which is concerning...but didn't seem to effect the visualization.
[Screen Shot](http://share.kevin-funk.com/ss.png)

Comment: Since Date1 and Year are created from Date, that's not possible. And the purpose of Date1 is to have the same year for all dates, in order to plot the data with one year on the x axis. Also, see my edits to the answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to me either. Have you had this happen before, that R can kind of be "lying" about the data that it has stored? As you can see from the screen shot, there's clearly a lot of blank fields...

Comment: No idea, how you created the screen-shot. Look at `head(gp)` and `tail(gp)`.